# Is it possible to start -webkit-animation at a paused state before clicking the run button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I'm currently doing an animation which moves the image from left to right.  One issue is it starts the animation before I click the run piggy button.

So I was wondering if its possible to start at a pause state and trigger the animation only once i press the run piggy button?

I'm not sure if this is the right direction I'm gong if i want to achieve what i said.

```
<div class="animation"></div>

<button id ="start">Run piggy</button>
<button id ="stop">Stop piggy</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(function()
    {
        $(".animation").css("animation-play-state","running");
    }); 

    $("#stop").click(function(){
        $(".animation").css("animation-play-state","paused");

    });
}); 

</script>
```

```
.animation
{
    height:500px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    background: url("Pig.gif") no-repeat left center; 
    -webkit-animation: test 10s infinite;
    animation: test 10s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes test 
{
    50% {background-position: right center;}
}
@keyframes test 
{
    50% {background-position: right center;}
}
```

Comment: The `-webkit-` prefix is for **experimental** features: It shouldn't be used in production and hasn't been needed in Chrome since 2015!

Comment: oh I'm new to this i only recently discovered this CSS function since i needed to do animation haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize with the `animation-play-state` as `paused` as well:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#start").click(function() {
    $(".animation").css("animation-play-state", "running");
  });

  $("#stop").click(function() {
    $(".animation").css("animation-play-state", "paused");

  });
});
```

```css
.animation {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 50px 0;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150") no-repeat left center;      
  animation: test 10s infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes test {
  50% {
    background-position: right center;
  }
}

@keyframes test {
  50% {
    background-position: right center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation"></div>

<button id="start">Run piggy</button>
<button id="stop">Stop piggy</button>
```

Comment: @darrylwong Glad it worked! Please accept the answer if it helped.